# Rastrear navegação com Analytics de páginas únicas que tem navegação em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

Recentemente criei uma [página pessoal](http://www.tiagocrizanto.com) e gostaria de rastrear as áreas mais visitadas do site.
O problema é que a página é composta de um arquivo único (ex: index.html) e a navegação é toda feita em JavaScript, ou seja, a página é carregada somente uma vez.
Há alguma forma no Google Analytics de rastrear a navegação dos usuários de acordo com a navegação do menu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O Google Analytics tem um sistema de Event Tracking que, acredito eu, se aplica à sua necessidade. Os detalhes estão aqui:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Você adiciona uma linha no ponto que quer medir, criando um evento (por exemplo, um clique num item do menu superior).

Se você usa o ga.js, fica assim:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'clique-no-menu', 'menu-superior', 'resumo']);
```

Se você usa o novo analytics.js, fica assim:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'menu-superior', 'resumo');
```

Depois é só ir na parte de Event Tracking do Google Analytics e montar sua análise.

Obs: Se você estiver aberto a outras opções, recomendo o [Mixpanel](http://mixpanel.com), que foi feito justamente para isso. A ideia é a mesma do Event Tracker do Google Analytics, mas particularmente, acho bem mais simples e intuitivo.

Comment: Muito bom. Essa solução serve para qualquer tipo de aplicação que seja assíncrona. Eu já implementei um site em Flash usando isso.